# Simplify formula $e^{-i0.5t}+e^{i0.5t}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I want to ask, how can I simplify this formula ?

$ e^{-i0.5t}+e^{i0.5t} $

I know that it can be simplify to $\cos(0.5t)$, but I don't know how :/

Comment: $\exp(\pm it)=\cos\;t\pm i\sin\;t$

Comment: In view of my answer below, note that $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$ and $\sin(-x) = - \sin(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)

$$e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$$

for $x=-0.5t$ , we obtain

$$e^{-0.5t}=e^{i\left( -0.5t\right) }=\cos \left( -0.5t\right) +i\sin \left(
-0.5t\right) $$

and for $x=0.5t$,

$$e^{0.5t}=\cos \left( 0.5t\right) +i\sin \left( 0.5t\right) .$$

Since $\cos$ is an [even function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_function#Even_functions) and $\sin$ an [odd function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_function#Even_functions), we obtain

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
e^{-0.5t}+e^{0.5t} &=&\cos \left( -0.5t\right) +i\sin \left( -0.5t\right)
+\cos \left( 0.5t\right) +i\sin \left( 0.5t\right)  \\
&=&\left( \cos \left( -0.5t\right) +\cos \left( 0.5t\right) \right) +i\left(
\sin \left( -0.5t\right) +\sin \left( 0.5t\right) \right)  \\
&=&\left( \cos \left( 0.5t\right) +\cos \left( 0.5t\right) \right) +i\left(
-\sin \left( 0.5t\right) +\sin \left( 0.5t\right) \right)  \\
&=&2\cos \left( 0.5t\right) +i\cdot 0 \\
&=&2\cos \left( 0.5t\right) 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 3):

Use $e^{ia}  = \cos a + i\sin a$, and find that the answer is slightly different from what you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

The more general answer to that is:
\begin{align}
\forall x \in \mathbb{R},\  \cos(x) & = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2} \\\\
\sin(x) & = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}
\end{align}
These equations can in turn be obtained by summing and subtracting the following two equations:
\begin{align}
\forall x \in \mathbb{R},\  e^{ix} & = \cos(x) + i\sin(x) \\\\
e^{-ix} & = \cos(x) - i\sin(x) \\\\
\end{align}